# Как сравнить два List<T>?

Tags: c#, list

Есть класс

```
public class DB
{
    public string vopros { get; set; }
    public string otvet { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

Есть два list

```
List<DB> list1 = new List<DB>();
List<DB> list2 = new List<DB>();
```

Как сравнить эти два `list`? чтобы например в `list3` были те элементы которые есть в первом и нет во втором?

Проходиться в цикле думаю не так хорошо. Может есть лучше решение?

Comment: Элементы в списках встречаются не более одного раза, или могут быть повторы? Во втором случае вам подойдет такое решение: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/68425/39186

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Если вам надо именно сравнить, то есть, выяснить, одинаковы списки или нет, к вашим услугам метод [`SequenceEquals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348567.aspx).

```
list1.SequenceEquals(list2)
```

Этот метод **сравнивает ещё и порядок элементов**.

Если вам нужно выяснить, совпадают ли наборы элементов без учёта порядка, эффективнее всего сконструировать из первой последовательности множество, и проверять равенство так:

```
new HashSet<DB>(list1).SetEquals(list2)
```

---

Если вам необходимо сравнивать не экземпляры, а значения, то вы либо определяете универсальный метод сравнения (реализуете `IEquatable<DB>`), либо передаёте вашу реализацию `IEqualityComparer<DB>` следующим образом:

```
list1.SequenceEquals(list2, comparer)
```

или соответственно

```
new HashSet<DB>(list1, comparer).SetEquals(list2)
```

Answer (score 12):

```
using System.Linq;
//....

var list3 = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

Если элементы нужно сравнивать по значению полей - то придется сделать одно из следующего:

- поменять `class` на `struct`
- переопределить в DB методы `Equals` и `GetHashCode`
- создать класс-наследник от `IEqualityComparer<DB>` и передать экземпляр этого класса вторым параметром в `Except`

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var item in list1)
{
    if (list2.Any(c => c.vopros == item.vopros))
    {
        list3.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, на данный момент, как мне кажется, правильным решением будет использовать метод

> Enumerable.SequenceEqual< TSource > (с) MSDN

И код будет выглядеть примерно так:

`bool isEqual = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);`

Answer (score 0):

Что бы корректно сравнить два списка объектов типа `Т` необходимо для этого типа реализовать `IEqualityComparer<T>`. 
Код пишу "на коленке", так что прошу прощения за возможные синтаксически ошибки.

```
public class DbComparer: IEqualityComparer<DB>
{
   pablic static DbComparer Comparer {get;} = new DbComparer();
   private DbComparer{}
   public bool Equels(DB one, DB two)
   {
           //описываем логику сравнения объектов заданного типа
           return string.Compare(one.vopros, two.vopros, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) == 0 &&
                  string.Compare(one.otvet, two.otvet, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) == 0 &&
                  string.Compare(one.url, two.url, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) == 0; 
   }
   pablic int GetHashCode(DB obj)
   {
           //реализация для .NET Core. для .NET Framework на память не помню
           return System.HashCode.Combine(obj.vopros, obj.otvet, obj.url )   
   }

}
```

Пример использования:

```
var hashOne = new HashSet<DB>(list1, DbComparer.Comparer);

var hashTwo = new HashSet<DB>(list2, DbComparer.Comparer);

hashOne.SymmetricExceptWith(hashTwo);
//SymmetricExceptWith оставит в hashOne только уникальные элементы
if (hashOne.Count > 0)
{
    //Если списки отличаются do something
}
```

Для небольших списков работает быстро, а для больших не тестил.